# Why does the window of a program called via CreateProcess show up in spite of SW_HIDE and CREATE_NO_WINDOW?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I try to call another program from my exe and I want it to execute silently in the background. (Since this call will happen to be very often, a window popping up is not acceptable.)

May way of doing it is this:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cl, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
                   CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) return -1;
else
{
  WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
  CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
  CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
  return 0;
}
```

The process is created and the desired program runs but unfortunately, the window shows up despite the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` and `SW_HIDE` flags.
Am I missing something / doing something wrong?

I figured out that I might be able to go for

1. get the process id from the process handle via `GetProcessId`
2. use `EnumWindows` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to find the matching window
3. use the obtained `HWND` to call `ShowWindow` with `SW_HIDE`

but that's cumbersome and I think `SW_HIDE` should work "out of the box" when creating the process, anyway.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think you telling it to be hidden only affects the fourth argument to `WinMain`, which the program can use or not use as it likes.

Comment: So there's no way to really force a program to be hidden?

Comment: I feel terrible for even saying this, but it might technically work (with no trouble of timing while finding the window and it flashing on the screen) if you started it on a different desktop, depending what it does. There *has* to be something cleaner than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value you supply in the `wShowWindow` field is passed to the `WinMain` entry point of the newly launched function, but it is only advisory - it's completely up to the new process as to whether it shows its window or not.

The standard/recommended behaviour when showing your app's main window is to call `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);` and `SW_SHOWNORMAL` in this instance means "use whatever value was passed to `WinMain`" but again, it's up to the process as to whether or not it does this.

One way you could get what you want is with a `WH_CBT` hook (see the docs for `SetWindowsHookEx`). This would let you hook the window creation and reposition it off-screen or stop it being shown altogether.

Comment: I forgot about the CBT hook option. Accessibility would work as well, and not require injection.

Comment: I don't think a CBT hook requires injection specifically, you just need your code to be in a DLL (i.e. if it does need to be injected, the system takes care of it for you).

Comment: I'll have a look at this. Thanks so far!

Comment: @JonathanPotter, Yeah, and that still has the disadvantages.

Comment: Global hooks are still something to avoid, in general, especially if accessibility hooks will work instead.

Answer (score -3):

Else ways secretive launch the application using CreateProcess +/- HCBT: window -> message-only, window -> WS_EX_LAYERED (alpha = 0), window -> NULLREGION, STATRTUPINFO.lpDesktop ...

Comment: I have no idea what this answer is trying to say.

Comment: Really? You don't want to assume that maybe I'm not a total idiot and improve your answer to be more clear? It doesn't occur to you that I might not be the only one who is confused?

Comment: I *think* kero is trying to say that there are several different ways to launch an app with its window hidden.  However, only 2 of them can be used with `CreateProcess()`, 1 of them does not apply to this discussion at all, and the other 2 require manually locating the window's `HWND` after `CreateProcess()` exits.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: "only 2 of them can be used with CreateProcess()" - "Really" :) ? My old workable demo (screenshot): http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/runhidden.png